# thumbnail creation vs image resizing?

Tags: performance, image-processing, thumbnails

I have an image gallery with pretty large images (around 1200/800) I want to create thumbnail (150/300px) navigation to these large images displayed near full size on the page.

My question, should I create 150/300px thumbnails or should I use the original images resized to 150/300px. Knowing the large images are already displayed and are to be downloaded by the client.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely create thumbnails. Even reducing an 800x800 down to 300x300 will take the file size down by a factor of 7. You can use more agressive JPEG compression on the thumbnails to get even more savings. If you load all the full size images on the navigation page you're going to be waiting a while to see the page come up, even if you end up needing all the same images later.

Comment: I don't think you get the point, the large images (5 to 8) have to be on the same page as the thumbnails and therefore downloaded by the client anyway. Don't you think adding smaller created thumbnails on the page would get the whole page even heavyer?

Comment: @chadocat, why do you have thumbnails on the page if it's already displaying the full size images? Generally when I see navigation thumbnails there's only one large image being displayed.

Comment: images are too large to be all seen in the screen, I need thumbnails to scroll down to the images they represent. I need to prevent page reloading on each thumbnail click...